# Python: insert ordered document in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

How can I insert an ordered document in mongodb?

- Python version: **3.11.0**
- Pymongo version: **4.3.3**

The following code does not work:

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from collections import OrderedDict
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from bson import son

URI="mongodb://localhost:1234"

client = MongoClient(host=URI, document_class=son.SON)

client.get_database("db").get_collection("col").insert_one(document=son.SON([
    ("first", ""),
    ("second", ""),
    ("third", ""),
    ("date",  datetime.now())
]))
```

In db the following gets stored:

```json
{
  "date": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1669566288397"
    }
  },
  "second": "",
  "first": "",
  "_id": ObjectId("6383757024f9019c642bb195"),
  "third": ""
}
```

Comment: How are you determining how the document is stored in the database/collection?

Comment: @rickhg12hs By how it's rendered in MongoDB Compass. Besides that, when I `find_one()` and `print()` it, it's disordered, in the ordered I posted in question

Comment: Check out [this discussion on field ordering with Python/`pymongo`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html?highlight=document_class#key-order-in-subdocuments-why-does-my-query-work-in-the-shell-but-not-pymongo).  If you follow the argument/parameter options there, does the document get stored as you want?